# What does "." in os.listdir(".") mean?

Tags: python

As indicated in the title, I don't know what the `"."` in `os.listdir(".")` means.

Does it mean all files and folders in the current directory?

Comment: @cottontail IMO this question lacks research effort, given `os.listdir` takes a path or path like object, searching what dot means in a path should easily reveal the answer. If it was a more general question maybe it might have had a better reception but then this is more specific asking about `os.listdir`, then on top of that we have a bounty that attracts more answers to something that already seems to be sufficiently answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's exactly right, the `"."` refers to [the current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

It is worth noting that every process has its own current working directory.

Answer (score 3):

According to the python3.12 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os#module-os), the `path` argument in **os.listdir** is set to default as `"."`, hence both `os.listdir(".")` and `os.listdir()` will produce the same output which is a list of the names of all the files and directories in the current working directory.

Argument `path` takes **path-like object**, which is a representation of a file system path. To get information on what path-like object is, please follow this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object).

Other combinations such as `".."` *(parent directory)*, `"./[folder_name]"` `"../.."` etc are also supported by `os.listdir`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, That's right. Please see this doc. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

s.listdir(path)
Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. The list is in arbitrary order. It does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.

Availability: Unix, Windows.

Changed in version 2.3: On Windows NT/2k/XP and Unix, if path is a Unicode object, the result will be a list of Unicode objects. Undecodable filenames will still be returned as string objects.

Answer (score 1):

**os.listdir(".")**  is used to list the current directory contents.

Other Options:

1. We can execute os.lisdir() in place of os.listdir(".").
2. If Desktop is the child sub directory in the current directory and you can lis t the contents in Desktop as os.listdir("Desktop")

Answer (score 1):

`"."` in `os.listdir(".")` in this code `"."` define as a current working directory. when you run this code it show all the files and directories in the current directory.

Comment: Duplicate of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40174611/7758804), and basically most of the other answers. This offers nothing new.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. This should display folders and files in directory where python script has been executed from if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Almost correct, the current working directory can change at any time.

Comment: @ncica please avoid spammin trivial edits that don't improve the posts you edit.

Comment: False. If you execute the script like this:

`python3 ./mydir/myscript.py`

The current working directory will be the directory where the script is executed, not the directory where the script is located (if not changed in the script itself).

Answer (score 0):

The "." in `os.listdir(".")` refers to the current working directory. The `os.listdir()` function returns a list of the names of all the files and directories in a given directory, and the current working directory is always represented by the "." character.

In other words, `os.listdir(".")` and `os.listdir()` are exactly the same thing. They both return a list of the names of all the files and directories in the current working directory, regardless of the script's location.

The `os.listdir("..")` function, on the other hand, returns a list of the names of all the files and directories in the parent directory. The parent directory is the directory that contains the current working directory.

Here is an example:

```
python
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)

contents = os.listdir()
print(contents)

contents_2 = os.listdir(".")
print(contents_2)

parent_contents = os.listdir("..")
print(parent_contents)
```

Output:

```
/home/fifthaxiom
['.gitignore', 'README.md', 'test.py']
['.gitignore', 'README.md', 'test.py']
['fifthaxiom']
```

As you can see, the output of the second and the third print statement is a list of the names of all the files and directories in the current working directory, and the output of the fourth print statement is a list of the names of all the files and directories in the parent directory.

Note that the `os.listdir()` function does not include the special entries `.` and `..` in the returned list. These entries represent the current directory and the parent directory, respectively.

You can also use the `os.path.dirname(__file__)` function to get the directory where the script is located. This can be useful if you want to write a script that can access files and directories relative to the script, regardless of what directory the script is executed in.

For example, the following script will print a list of all the files in the directory where the script is located:

```
python
import os

cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
contents = os.listdir(cwd)
print(contents)
```

Cheers!